# Can I change JMX attribute name in JMXFetch before pushing it to DataDog?

Tags: jmx, datadog

Is it possible to change JMX attribute name in JMXFetch so that a different name shows up in DataDog?

I currently have the following:

```
- include:
    domain: data
    attribute:
      - success
      - error
```

This would report two metrics in DataDog:

```
jmx.data.success
jmx.data.error
```

Is it possible to rename it in the yaml script to something more like:

```
jmx.com.abc.reporting.successCount
jmx.com.abc.reporting.errorCount
```

without the original names ever showing up in DataDog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very much possible, just use the alias property of the [attribute](http://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/java/#the-attribute-filter) filter:

```
- include:
    domain: data
    attribute:
      success:
        alias: jmx.com.abc.reporting.successCount
      error:
        alias: jmx.com.abc.reporting.errorCount
```